# Parse iOS SDK: Dynamic cell height for PFQueryTableViewController based on results from Query

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, heightforrowatindexpath

**Scenario**

I have an app that downloads data from my parse.com database and displays it into a PFQueryTableViewController. The PFQTVC has multiple (6) prototype cells each with their own reuseIdentifier as well as most importantly, their own height. I am currently using the following design to find the correct height for each `indexPath.row`...

**Currently**

*this works before enabling paging*

Each cell is unique as each one displays different types of information. So I am checking for each `self.objects` by each unique quality they have.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

                        // \!/ -trouble maker 
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *orientation = object[@"orientation"];

    NSNumber *height;

    if ([orientation  isEqual: @"left"] || [orientation  isEqual: @"right"]) {

        height = @400.0;
    }

    else if ([orientation  isEqual: @"up"] || [orientation  isEqual: @"down"]) {

        height = @500.0;
    }

    else if (blah blah blah) {

        //ect.
    }

    return [height floatValue];
}
```

This all works. That is, before I enable paging.

**When I enable paging**

Like most apps mine needs to be able to page through data, and that's what mine does. I set my `objectsPerPage` to 10 - *problem is, when I scroll down to that tenth cell and reload the next page...*

```
...reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'
```

**Reason**

When it loads the next page, `self.objects` in heightForRowAtIndexPath is an NSArray that does not get loaded with the new objects. This is causing my app to crash and making me very frustrated.

**Question**

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

```
NSNumber *height;

if (indexPath.row > self.objects.count) {

    height = @50.0;
}

else {

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *orientation = object[@"orientation"];

    if ([orientation  isEqual: @"left"] || [orientation  isEqual: @"right"]) {
        //HAS COMMENTS
        if ([[object objectForKey:@"comments"]intValue] > 0) {


            height = @618.0;

        }

        else {


            //NO COMMENTS BUT HAS LIKES
            if ([[object objectForKey:@"likes"]count] > 0) {


                height = @398.0;

            }
            //HAS NOTHING
            else {


                height = @381.0;

            }

        }

    }

    else if ([orientation  isEqual: @"up"] || [orientation  isEqual: @"down"]) {

        if ([[object objectForKey:@"comments"]intValue] > 0) {


            height = @727.0;

        }

        else {


            if ([[object objectForKey:@"likes"]count] > 0) {


                height = @508.0;

            }

            else {

                height = @490.0;

            }

        }

    }

    return [height floatValue];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have pagination enabled, Parse add's a "Load More" cell at that 11th cell. There is no 11th object in self.objects though. You will want to check indexPath.row < self.objects.count and return a different height for the Load More cell.

This should prevent that error:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // \!/ -trouble maker
    if (indexPath.row== self.objects.count) return 40.0;

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *orientation = object[@"orientation"];

    NSNumber *height;

    if ([orientation  isEqual: @"left"] || [orientation  isEqual: @"right"]) {

        height = @400.0;
    }

    else if ([orientation  isEqual: @"up"] || [orientation  isEqual: @"down"]) {

        height = @500.0;
    }

    else if (blah blah blah) {

        //ect.
    }

    return [height floatValue];
}
```

When I implement a slight delay for the loadNextPage it works great. There must be a method that is attempting to access the self.objects array before it is loaded properly.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row >= self.objects.count)
    {
        // this method gets called when the cell is scrolling into view, but also when it's first added to the table view
        // we only care about the first case
        if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [self performSelector:@selector(loadNextPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain clearly I apologize. Im using this little handy method as well. Does this matter? [Method](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfqeurytableviewcontroller-load-next-page-automatically). I think because I have this I don't need a Load More cell.

Comment: More than likely it calls the heightForRow method before willDisplayCell is called. Even if it didn't the next page is probably loaded asynchronously so there would still be a chance that it could get that "Load More" cell.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I posted my code above, but it still says NSArrayM 0..10 out of bounds and all.

Comment: Forget my last comment. I messed it up but now I'm trying what you suggested and i may be on to something here. Ill keep you posted.

Comment: After testing out the automatic page loading from your link I added a slight delay and it seems to work, something(likely in parse's code)  may be loading trying to access the array sooner than it should.